# Where (and what?) are the fuses in Renault Megane Grande Scenic?

Tags: fuse, renault, megane

There are some in the glove compartment.

There are some 4 or 5 under the drawer under the passenger seat.

There are some somewhere under the bonnet I believe.

The car manual describes some but does not describe them all.

The fuses I have actually never had a problem with so far. But it was handy on occasion to reset electronics of one system and not whole car (and have to enter alarm code and reprogram windows e.t.c.).

Can anyone help fill in the gaps in knowledge?

Pics of glove compartment box: . . .
[image: fuses in glove box]
[image: fuse icons left]
[image: fuse icons right]

Pic of fuses under drawer under passenger seat:
[image: fuses under passenger seat]

The white 25A fuse under passenger seat is for Automatic Parking Brake.

Comment: Presumably the ones in the first photo are self explanatory, seeing as you have all the icons on the lid to guide you, or are you asking about them too?

Comment: would be good to have an exact explain for each icon for reference. I'll put in what I can in time. unless someone else does it first :-)

Comment: Fuses under P seat . are also under CD Changer.. and get wet easily.

Answer (score 2):

In the second and third images, starting at the top and working to the right:

Top row -

1. Fans
2. Windows
3. Sun roof

Middle row -

1. Antilock Brakes (ABS)
2. Radio
3. Brake lights
4. Fog lights (?)
5. Window
6. Window
7. Coupe Console - someone says it is "Consumer for clock / radio" (?)
8. Horn
9. Wiper
10. ALIM/UCH - manual says "common power" (?)

Third row -

1. Interior lights
2. Cigarette lighter
3. Door locks (?)
4. (Blank)
5. Side view mirror defrost

As for the fourth picture, I'm not sure what these are for. Hopefully someone else knows. It may be part of the Body Control Module (BCM). With all of the yellow wiring going into it, it could also be airbag related (assuming the yellow wires are actually going into it and not just under it).

EDIT: Fuses under passenger seat (4th picture) (left to right):

1. big lavender thing - relay? for . . . (?)
2. red 10amp - (?)
3. red 10amp - (?)
4. yellow 20amp - arm console cigarette lighter
5. white 25amp - Automatic Parking Brake.

Comment: Anyone see fit to add to or correct where I have the ?'s please feel free. If you don't have enough rep to modify, just leave me a comment and I'll make the change.